# setting a variable based on ifstream

Tags: c++, while-loop, char, project, ifstream

i'm doing a project, and i need to set 3 variables for each time  reading a character from a document. here's what i have so far:

```
while(instream.get(value)){
    value = convertToUpper(value);
    cout << value;

    oldestval = oldval;
    oldval = value;
}
```

where `oldval`, `oldestval`, and `value` are all `char`. `instream` is my instance of `ifstream` and `convertToUpper()` just makes the char uppercase. so if you can't tell, i need `oldval` to equal what `value` was, and then set value. the problem i have is that i HAVE to have it in this loop, because this loop reads the whole file to the end. my question is, from what you have seen, how would i fix my problem? i can provide the whole program if it helps. let me know and thanks for the help! thanks :D

Comment: Still don't get what is your problem.

Comment: *"how would i fix my problem?"* You might start by describing the actual *problem*. Your "question" just describes your algorithm and what you need from it, and your code at least *appears* to meet that need. So... whats the **problem** ? Do you want oldval set to value *prior* to the case conversion??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

sorry bout the confusion. i fixed it myself by just adding another `char` variable, and then setting value to that. lolz sorry for wasting your time D: